# Extract keys from a dictionary as a flat list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary objects like below:

```
{('look', 'toward'): 1,
 ('new', 'cage'): 3,
 ('think', 'surpris'): 0,
 ('go', 'see'): 1 }
```

What I would like to do is to extract a each words separately in order like 
'look', 'toward', 'new', 'cage'....up to end without use values().
How can I extract these words ?
Is it better to make a list instead of a dictionary ? 
It would be really appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Comment: You do not have to use `values()` since the *values* you are after are the `keys` of the dict and not the `values`. Conserning the order, it cannot be guaranteed since dict do not understand this concept (or did not up to version 3.6 but that is just an implementation detail one cannot count on).

Comment: OK. Thank you for pointing my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only interested in the *key*, not the "values". The keys are what you use to index the dictionary.

A clean approach is calling `dict.keys()` and flattening it, with `itertools.chain`. `import itertools`, first.

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.keys()))
['think', 'surpris', 'go', 'see', 'look', 'toward', 'new', 'cage']
```

Beware, order of the returned strings are not guaranteed, since python's dictionaries aren't ordered on versions older than 3.6.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
d = {('look', 'toward'): 1,
 ('new', 'cage'): 3,
 ('think', 'surpris'): 0,
 ('go', 'see'): 1 }

[kk for k in d for kk in k]
# returns:
['look', 'toward', 'think', 'surpris', 'new', 'cage', 'go', 'see']
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to extract if a is your dict:

```
>>> for key, value in a.items():
...     print(key[0],key[1],value)
...
look toward 1
new cage 3
think surpris 0
go see 1
```

You can play that you want:

```
>>> for key, value in a.items():
...     print(f'{key[0]}: {value}')
...     print(f'{key[1]}: {value}')
...
look: 1
toward: 1
new: 3
cage: 3
think: 0
surpris: 0
go: 1
see: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data={('look', 'toward'): 1,
 ('new', 'cage'): 3,
 ('think', 'surpris'): 0,
 ('go', 'see'): 1 }



print([k for i in data.keys() for k in i ])
```

output:

```
[['new', 'cage'], ['go', 'see'], ['look', 'toward'], ['think', 'surpris']]
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is get a list of the keys of your dictionary which you can get with `my_dict.keys()` and merge tuples in there like so:

```
my_dict = {('look', 'toward'): 1,
  ('new', 'cage'): 3,
  ('think', 'surpris'): 0,
  ('go', 'see'): 1 }

my_tuple = tuple()
for key in my_dict.keys():
  new_list = new_list + key
print(my_tuple)
```

this will print:

```
('look', 'toward', 'new', 'cage', 'think', 'surpris', 'go', 'see')
```

which you can iterate now just normally:

```
for item in my_tuple:
  print(item)
```

which will spit out:

```
look
toward
new
cage
think
surpris
go
see
```